# AngularJS ng-repeat does not show JSON array

Tags: angularjs, json

i've a little problem with Angular ng-repaet and an JSON-File. Ng-repeat does not show any content.

Here is my JSON file(articles.json):

```
[
  {"id":"1", "name" : "Pizza Tobmes", "price" : 3.50},
  {"id":"2", "name" : "Pizza Freddy", "price" : 2.90},
  {"id":"3", "name" : "Pizza Unicorn", "price" : 6.66},
  {"id":"4", "name" : "Pizza Doppel Unicorn", "price" : 12.00},
  {"id":"5", "name" : "Schnitzel Unicorn", "price" : 15.33}
]
```

Here is my HTML part:

```html
<table ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl as art">
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <tr  ng-repeat="article in articles">

        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price | currency : '€ '}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
               >Hinzufügen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And finaly my app.js

```js
function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('UnicornPizzaService', [])
        .controller('ArticlesCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $http.get('articles.json').then(function(response) {
                $scope.articles = response.data;
            });
        });
})();
```

The only thing I see is, the right count of "hinzufügen"-buttons. I don't know what's the problem.How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ArticlesCtrl as art`, so in order to access articles under scope, you have to prefix it with `art`.

```
<table ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl as art">
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <tr  ng-repeat="article in art.articles">

        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price | currency : '€ '}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
               >Hinzufügen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all. If I try this

```html
<table ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl as art">
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="article in art.articles">

        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price | currency : '€ '}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
               ng-click="cart.addArticle(article);">Hinzufügen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I dont see anything. Even the "Hinzufügen"-Buttons are gone. If I try this

```html
<table ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl">
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
    <tr ng-repeat="article in articles">

        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price | currency : '€ '}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
               ng-click="cart.addArticle(article);">Hinzufügen</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can see the "Hinzufügen"-Buttons again.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ArticlesCtrl',function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.articles = [
  {"id":"1", "name" : "Pizza Tobmes", "price" : 3.50},
  {"id":"2", "name" : "Pizza Freddy", "price" : 2.90},
  {"id":"3", "name" : "Pizza Unicorn", "price" : 6.66},
  {"id":"4", "name" : "Pizza Doppel Unicorn", "price" : 12.00},
  {"id":"5", "name" : "Schnitzel Unicorn", "price" : 15.33}
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <table ng-controller="ArticlesCtrl as art">
  <tr>
    <th>Nr.</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Preis</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr ng-repeat="article in art.articles">
        <td>{{article.id}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price | currency : '€ '}}</td>
        <td><a href class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
               >Hinzufügen</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```